# remote machine 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, remote-debugging

I have ssh into a windows machine through my linux machine using putty. How do i find if the machine i have ssh into is 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: Try `systeminfo`? I'm not sure how it looks like on 64-bit computer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 64-bit build of OpenSSH is installed on your Windows host, check if there is a C:\Windows\SysWow64 directory?

If it's a 32-bit build of OpenSSH, you can do the opposite and check for system files that *should* be in C:\Windows\system32\ but aren't as you're being invisibly redirected to C:\Windows\SysWow64 instead (bcdedit.exe, for example, is in system32 but not in syswow64).